# Can I find a museum pass in New York?

Tags: usa, international-travel, new-york-city, museums, public-holidays

I'd like to visit New York next year and I was wondering if there is a sightseeing pass available so as to see more on a budget. I plan to stay for 10 days.

Comment: See also [Is the NYC CityPASS a good deal?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68705/is-the-nyc-citypass-a-good-deal). Note the the Met will, sadly, be ended its pay-as-you-wish policy for non-New Yorkers soon, so that can change the calculations somewhat.

Answer (score 2):

Try this [New York City pass](https://www.citypass.com/new-york). I have used the Chicago city pass in the past but I was only in the city for a day. You are in for 10 days so might be worthwhile checking how much you would pay for all without the pass and see if it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

I have been in NY in 2016. I saw two main options: [New York City Pass](https://www.citypass.com/new-york) and [Smart Destinations](https://pt.smartdestinations.com/new-york-attractions-and-tours/_d_Nyc-p1.html?pass=Nyc_Prod_Exp). I chose Smart Destinations. It worked fine to me.